# Angular 2+ - Pass array of data while routing to a child component

Tags: angular

I am willing to pass an array while routing, for example I have the following :

```
<div *ngFor="let info of users">
<div [routerLink]="['/users']" [queryParams]="{userId:info.id}">
</div>
```

The above code works fine and shows the below URL :

```
http://example.com/users?userId=302932
```

However, I willing to have something like the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let info of users">
<div [routerLink]="['/users']" [queryParams]="{userId:info.id, userData:info}">
</div>
```

I would like to keep the same URL as above:

```
http://example.com/users?userId=302932
```

But with passing the array `info` to the child component, I've tried several workaround, but in the end I got `undefined` on the child component and I was not able to send the array to the child component.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special out-of-the-box that you can use in order to implement this. The idea behind the router is to encode certain state into the URL. If you need more data, you're supposed to fetch that additional data.

Since the user can type in the URL (or visit a link from anoter site, or have it bookmarked, or have it shared via an email), the page must work on the first load, hence it can't rely on the route that called it.

What you want to do is optimize the flow in case the user is navigating through the app. In that case, what you should do it **use a service** to store the data into the cache (a singleton service) when navigating. In the component that you want to opitimize, inject the service an read its value on component's initialization. If there is something in the cache, use it. Otherwise fire the request to the server to fetch the data.

Comment: By saying `use a service` you mean for example to store that array in `localStorage` for example and retrieve its content in the child component ?

Comment: No, I mean store it in a variable in a service.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can send array in the following format, as object, and later, you can take array from that object...

```html
 <div   [routerLink]="[ 'path', { array:[1,2,3] } ]" ></div>
```

Comment: That's not how routing is supposed to work. The URL should contain the resource ID and optionally a slug for better SEO, but not the whole state no the page.